# if any item in array === x then return false

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var array = [false,true,true,true,true];
```

I would like to return false if any item in array is false and only return true if all items are true. is there a fast way to do this with out all the boilerplate? in python i would use the "if is in" syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case you'd use the [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method. The method expects every return value in each iteration to evaluate to `true` so simply passing the current value, which all happen to be a booleans will suffice without any additional logic.

```js
var array = [false, true, true, true, true].every(bool => bool);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! it also looks clean and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: You can use `.indexOf()`. This example will return `false` if `myArray` contains `false`, and return `true` otherwise:

```
function hasNoFalse(myIndex) {
  return myArray.indexOf(false) === -1;
}
```

Option 2: You can use `.some()` or `.every()` :

> I would like to return false if any item in array is false

```
return myArray.some((val) => val === false)
```

> and only return true if all items are true.

```
return myArray.every((val) => val === true)
```

Comment: *"If you need to avoid ES6 stuff, you can use .indexOf()"* – I don't think you'll run into compatibility issues given, `every()` was implemented in ES5

Comment: @CarlEdwards Good point. Not many people are in ES3-only environments. :-D I'll change the text....

Comment: `.some()` is nice as it is symmetrical with `.every()` and lexically self-documenting whereas `indexOf()` seems a bit obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.indexOf(element)` and if the result is greater than -1, then there's that element in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
a.every(function(val){
    return val == true;
});
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: @Intervalia I am no javascript expert. But I dont think a correct answer deserves a downvote even if it is a slow one.

Answer (score 0):

While everyone is using arrow function, this is one way to do it without it

```
function myFunction(array) {
var b = 0;
array.forEach(function(element) {

    if(element)
        b++
});
if(b == array.length)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
}
```

I wrote this only for people who don't know what arrow is.